# Create a reduced size communicator for REDUCE operations

Tags: performance, fortran, mpi

Sometimes not all ranks are needed for a compute task. I am trying to tailor the communicator to the need but MPI appear to stop after the reduced communicator has been constructed (rank=8). MPI debug says 'fatal error in PMPI_Comm_rank: invalid communicator'. My essential code is:

```
PROGRAM mpi_comm_create
USE MPI
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER comm,i,ierr,group,rank,rank1,root,size,size1,redcomm,redgroup
INTEGER,ALLOCATABLE::ranks(:)
comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD
!---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CALL MPI_init(ierr)
CALL MPI_comm_size(comm,size,ierr)
CALL MPI_comm_rank(comm,rank,ierr)
CALL MPI_comm_group(comm,group,ierr)
!--------------------------------------------------------------------------
size1=size-2
ALLOCATE(ranks(size1))
ranks(1:size1)=[0:size1-1]
!---------------------------------------------------------------------------
!Define new group redgroup and communicator redcomm with size1 processes
CALL MPI_group_incl(group,size1,ranks,redgroup,ierr)
CALL MPI_comm_create(comm,redgroup,redcomm,ierr)
CALL MPI_comm_rank(redcomm,rank1,ierr)
!---------------------------------------------------------------------------
!Use redcomm in a REDUCE operation
!---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CALL MPI_group_free(redgroup,ierr)
CALL MPI_comm_free(redcomm,ierr)
!---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CALL MPI_FINALIZE(ierr)
DEALLOCATE(ranks)
STOP; END
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly use MPI_COMM_SPLIT - it is easier as indicated in replies to your essentially identical earlier question.

Secondly the error is because all processes are making the second call to mpi_comm_rank, but not all processes are in the communicator specified in that call.

Comment: As the REDUCE operation is in the core of the parallellization code,  low overhead is of interest. In one of the answers to my question on MPI_COMM_SPLIT it was argued that MPI_COMM_CREATE was more efficient. Any comment about that?

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of the crash is ranks [size1:size-1] invoke `MPI_Comm_rank()` on `MPI_COMM_NULL`, which is not allowed since `MPI_COMM_NULL` is not a valid communicator. In order to get rid of the crash, you can replace

```
CALL MPI_comm_rank(redcomm,rank1,ierr)
```

with

```
IF (MPI_COMM_NULL.ne.redcomm) CALL MPI_comm_rank(redcomm,rank1,ierr)
```

From a performance point of view (which is what your question is really about), i do not expect any significant difference between `MPI_Comm_create()` and `MPI_Comm_split()`.

From a semantic point of view, both `MPI_Comm_split()` and `MPI_Comm_create()` are collective operations, and they must be invoked by **all** MPI tasks from `MPI_COMM_WORLD`. If MPI tasks [size1:size-1] cannot/should not be involved in the creation of `redcomm`, then you can use `MPI_Comm_create_group()`, that should only be called by MPI tasks [0:size1-1].

If all tasks can be involved in the creation of `redcomm`, then i suggest you stick to `MPI_Comm_split()` in order to keep your code simpler. If you do not need MPI tasks [size1:size-1] being part of a valid communicator `redcomm`, then i also suggest you use `color=MPI_UNDEFINED` on these tasks, so `redcomm` will be `MPI_COMM_NULL` instead of a valid communicator. But keep in mind `MPI_COMM_NULL` is not a valid communicator, so it is up to your code **not** to invoke `MPI_Comm_rank()`, `MPI_Comm_size()`, `MPI_Comm_free()` and other subroutines on it.

Comment: i do not think this is necessary. but you might consider upvoting some answers and accepting one of them if they answered your question.